# How to copy column from each sheet? - VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file that generates a different number of sheets each time with different product names.

I would like to do a copleteness check for this file that would copy the following 2 columns from the 4th sheet (code below**) to the end of the sheets:

1. The first column with the name of the product ("Product") - Row number 2
2. The second specified column after the name ("NO_POLIS_IF") - the column sometimes changes places and is 5 or 11, etc., so it must be identified by the name in row number 2

I managed to write this identification:

```
Dim sh as Worksheet
Dim strSearch As String
strSearch = "NO_POLIS_IF"

Set s = sh.Rows(2). Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole,
 SearchOrder:=xlByrows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, searchFormat:=False)

If Not s Is nothing then 
c = s.Column
End If
```

And then it would paste the data from these columns into one worksheet aggregated one below the other ("AggrProdCheck")

Can someone please help me with this?

**

```
For Each sh In Sheets
IF sh.Name <> "Config" and sh.Name <> "Summary" and sh.Name <> "Check" Then
...
```

Comment: Depending on how you have your workbook setup, you could use `If sh.index > 4 then`     Are your columns always in different orders?\

Comment: I have  19 sheets and column NO_POLIS_IF appears in a different place each time. In the range of 14 to 22column

Comment: Continuing your "**", `With sh` ..next line: `Set rgProd = .Range("A3", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` ..next line: `ColNum = .Rows(2).Find("NO_POLIS_IF").Column` ..next line: `Set rgToBeCopied = Union(rgProd, rgProd.Offset(0, ColNum - 1))` ..next line: `Set rgToBePasted = Sheets("AggrProdCheck").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(rgProd.Rows.Count, 2)` ..next line:  `rgToBePasted.Value = rgToBeCopied.Value` ..next line `End With` ..next line `End If` ..next line `Next`. If I understand you correctly.

Comment: <3 Thank you, let's add this code as answer i will pin it as best

Comment: Should i do ``` Dim ColNum As Integer``` ye?